# 504 Gateway timeout returned by web service unless "Accept-Language" header present. Why?

Tags: .net, http-headers, http-status-code-504

I've been trying to access a web service using System.Net.WebRequest to make a GET request. This would return a "504 Gateway timeout" error.

However the same web service would return data successfully when accessed through a browser.

After comparing the request headers of the WebRequest and Browser requests I identified that the header "Accept-Language" had to be present even if the value of it was empty.

Any ideas as to why "Accept-Language" has to be present?

Comment: Did you every resolve this? We have a similar problem and also suspect the load balancer.

Comment: I'm afraid that I've never got to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

The service -- and it would perhaps help to know what it is -- most likely returns dates or text or other information that needs to be localized.

Without the `Accept-Language` header it's not possible to do this.

Comment: The problem might be down to a load balancer. Currently investigating further.